# How to fix 'Objects are not valid as a React child'

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/jd-fillmore/ff7-dex/tree/development).

I'm getting this error when trying to use filter() through a big array of objects (defined as 'filteredCharacters'), and render only those match the id of '6' to the screen (only one does).

I console.log(filteredCharacters), and I can clearly see in console that it works. But for some reason, I'm getting a "Objects are not valid as a React child" error thrown.

The code below is from /components/content.js, in the Codesandbox link above.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Intro from '../intro/intro';

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    // Grab the 'characters' object from App.js, and assign it to 'this.props'
    const { characters } = this.props;

    // Filter the chracters and return only whose 'id' belongs to that of '6'
    const filteredCharacters = characters.filter(characters => {
      if (characters.id === 6) {
        return (
          <div className="characters" key={characters.id}>
            <p>Name: {characters.Name}</p>
            <p>ID: {characters.id}</p>
            <p>Job: {characters.Job}</p>
            <p>Age: {characters.Age}</p>
            <p>Weapon: {characters.Weapon}</p>
            <p>Height: {characters.Height}</p>
            <p>Birthdate: {characters.Birthdate}</p>
            <p>Birthplace: {characters.Birthplace}</p>
            <p>Bloodtype: {characters.Bloodtype}</p>
            <p>Description: {characters.Description}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    });

    // Check to see if it logs properly (it does)
    console.log(filteredCharacters);

    // When trying to render this to the screen below, it doesn't work

    return (
      <div>
        {filteredCharacters}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: `filter` takes in a predicate that returns a boolean to decide what elements to keep if true, or to skip if false

Comment: members of `filteredCharacters` array are objects and this error comes  while rendering those objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` will only create a new array with all the elements that returned a truthy value from the function.

You can instead use `filter` first to get the relevant characters, and then use `map` on the new array to get the JSX you want to render.

```
const filteredCharacters = characters
  .filter(character => character.id === 6)
  .map(character => (
    <div className="characters" key={character.id}>
      <p>Name: {character.Name}</p>
      <p>ID: {character.id}</p>
      <p>Job: {character.Job}</p>
      <p>Age: {character.Age}</p>
      <p>Weapon: {character.Weapon}</p>
      <p>Height: {character.Height}</p>
      <p>Birthdate: {character.Birthdate}</p>
      <p>Birthplace: {character.Birthplace}</p>
      <p>Bloodtype: {character.Bloodtype}</p>
      <p>Description: {character.Description}</p>
    </div>
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Tholle's answer, you could combine those operations into one with `reduce`

```js
const filteredCharacters = characters
  .reduce((acc, character)  => {

    if (character.id !== 6) return acc;

    acc.push(<div className="characters" key={character.id}>
      <p>Name: {character.Name}</p>
      <p>ID: {character.id}</p>
      <p>Job: {character.Job}</p>
      <p>Age: {character.Age}</p>
      <p>Weapon: {character.Weapon}</p>
      <p>Height: {character.Height}</p>
      <p>Birthdate: {character.Birthdate}</p>
      <p>Birthplace: {character.Birthplace}</p>
      <p>Bloodtype: {character.Bloodtype}</p>
      <p>Description: {character.Description}</p>
    </div>);

    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using one simple object to behave as a node in the HTML structure of the component you are writing. One of the best practices to use react in such cases is to create and then call this as a react component itself.

Following is your code that now has a separate component that can be called on need:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Intro from '../intro/intro';

const FilteredCharcters = characters => {
  characters.filter(character => {
   if (character.id === 6) {
     return (
       <div className="characters" key={character.id}>
         <p>Name: {character.Name}</p>
         <p>ID: {character.id}</p>
         <p>Job: {character.Job}</p>
         <p>Age: {character.Age}</p>
         <p>Weapon: {character.Weapon}</p>
         <p>Height: {character.Height}</p>
         <p>Birthdate: {character.Birthdate}</p>
         <p>Birthplace: {character.Birthplace}</p>
         <p>Bloodtype: {character.Bloodtype}</p>
         <p>Description: {character.Description}</p>
       </div>
     )
   }
 });

class Content extends Component {

  render() {
  const { characters } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <FilteredCharacters characters={characters} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Content;
```